# Trouble compiling using Eclipse CDT with alternate toolchain

Tags: eclipse-cdt, toolchain

I'm trying to use Eclipse CDT (Version: Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149) to build and debug my c/c++ project in RHEL6 64 bit Linux, and I'm having issues.  I've done what I thought was necessary to use an alternate toolchain to perform the compilation, but something seems to be missing, as eclipse says that it compiled the source, but it didn't really do it.

For the setup I went to C/C++ Project Properties -> C/C++ Build configuring the "Debug" configuration, on the "Builder Settings" tab I unchecked the "Use default build command" checkbox, and entered the name of my toolchain "mk all" into the "Build command" field.  I then unchecked the "Generate Makefiles automatically" checkbox. Next I changed the "Build Directory" field to be "".  Lastly I went to the "Behavior" tab and unchecked the "Build on resource save (Auto build)" checkbox and changed the "make build target" to be "all ${selected_resource_loc}" .

Now, when I go to my project, and select a subdirectory that needs to be built, and then click on the build button on the toolbar this is what happens:

1) I see the "Build Project..." in the progress window briefly

2) The CDT build console displays this:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project myproj ****

mk all

**** Build Finished ****
```

The above is what I see when my code needs rebuilt, does not need rebuilt, and when there are errors in the compilation.  I can verify this by opening a bash terminal and typing "mk" in the directory I want to build.  When I compile from the terminal, I can see the compiler output (success and errors etc..), but eclipse shows me nothing of the sorts.

I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what.  Does anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

--update--

I found out what part of my issue was, which turned out to be that my build tool was invoked via a bash script without a shebang at the top.

My next issue is that the build is always invoked from the root of the project, which has no makefile.  I have tried putting the "${selected_resource_loc}" variable into both the "make build target" field, but it does not seem to have the correct effect as my "mk all" command seems to be invoked with the variable being translated to an empty string every time.  Any ideas on this side issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'[DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far ...](http://xkcd.com/979/)'

I sorta solved my issue. I had asked a friend with a similar setup to try this out, and he got it to work on the first try. I then concluded that it was either my install or my project. Thus, I proceeded to delete the project files (.project and .cproject) and recreate the project. After I completed that, it seemed to work like a charm. I must have selected an obscure incompatible project option, that caused something to not expand the ${selected_resource_loc} variable. Weird. I hope this helps someone along the way.